# How do you obtain and use a value of type void?

Tags: c++, void

I was given a piece of code that uses `void()` as an argument. The code doesn't compile... obviously?

Can we instantiate anything of type `void`? I believed the answer was no, with the exception of a `void*`. For example:

1. Writing the function `void askVoid(void param) {}` errors:

> A parameter may not have `void` type

2. Writing the function `void askNaught() {}` and calling it with askNaught(void())` errors:

> error C2660: `takeNaught`: function does not take 1 arguments

3. Writing the templatized function `template <typename T> void takeGeneric(T param) {}` and calling it with `takeGeneric(void())` errors:

> error C2893: Failed to specialize function template `void takeGeneric(T)`

4. Declaring `void voidType` errors:

> Incomplete type is not allowed

5. Declaring `auto autoVoid = void()` errors:

> Cannot deduce `auto` type

6. Declaring `void* voidPtr` works fine, but `remove_pointer_t<decltype(voidPtr)> decltypeVoid` errors:

> error C2182: `decltypeVoid`: illegal use of type `void`

That's it, right? There is no place for `void()` in C++ is there? This is just bad code I've been given, right?

Comment: You can return a `void` function call in a function that returns `void`: `void a() {}; void b() { return a(); }`. That's kind of an expression of type void.

Comment: @rodrigo In this case `a()` would be executed? That's very odd, but my compiler doesn't complain. Similar to just calling `a()` as the last line of `b()` I guess.

Comment: Yes, it is the same as just calling the function and then returning. It is a special rule in the C++ type system to ease the writing of templates: `template<typename T> T foo() { return bar<T>(); }`. Or else you would need a template specialization just to remove the spurious `return`s when `T=void`.

Comment: @rodrigo Amazing, I see the importance of being able to call `return` with a `void` when you put it in that context. I'd suggest you put it into an answer, but it looks like [Black got there first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37701815/2642059), although that does not use the type it does in effect what I was asking about.

Comment: Actually, writing @Black 's answer just covers the original question, IMO. I invite him to copy the template stuff from my comment if he wishes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The expression `void()` is a prvalue of type `void` and can be used anywhere such an expression may be used, which [[basic.fundamental]/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#9) helpfully provides a list:

- As an expression-statement: `void();`
- As the second or third operand of a conditional operator: `true ? throw 1 : void()`
- As an operand of the comma operator: `++it1, void(), ++it2`
- As the operand of `decltype` or `noexcept`: `using my_void = decltype(void()); static_assert(noexcept(void()), "WAT");`
- In a `return` statement of a function returning (possibly cv-qualified) `void`: `const void f() { return void(); }`
- As an operand of an explicit conversion to (possibly cv-qualified) `void`: `static_cast<const void>(void())`

An expression of type `void` can also be used as the operand of `typeid`, but `void()` in particular would be parsed as a type, not an expression, in this context.

Comment: Does the standard mention anywhere that `void()` is non-throwing? Or, put differently, how are we expected to know what `noexcept(void())` returns?

Answer (score 12):

C++ (and I say C++, not C) allows ([§6.6.3 comma 2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#2)) functions with `void` return type to return a `void` expression, that is:

```
void foo() { return void(); }
```

But notice it is *not* constructing a temporary `void`!

Comment: Fascinating. So this is just equivalent to `return` right?

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes, it's right. @rodrigo gave an immediate consequence of this usage i.e. when you call a function returning `void`.

Comment: Yeah I get the impression that that's actual the functional use of this to compress a closing function call (@rodrigo's `a()`) and an early return from a function returning `void` into one compound statement.

Comment: This is used heavily in generic code to avoid having to special case `void` returning functions whose result you are "passing through".

Answer (score 10):

You can take a `void()` as function parameter:

```
void test(void()) { ... }
```

Which expands to:

```
void test(void (*)())
```

Which is a function pointer to a method which returns void and takes no arguments.

Full example:

```
void abc() {}
void test(void()) { }

int main() {
    test(abc);
}
```

Comment: No, if you use `test(void)` you are indicating a method which takes no arguments (which was required in C) - or am I wrong?

Comment: you're right, I realized my comment was off-topic and deleted it, feel free to delete both of our comments as the matter is resolved

Comment: @sokkyoku I think it wasn't necessary to delete it, it could have helped others too to clarify why the braces matter :)

Comment: Fair enough, it has no impact in C++ though, you can still specify a lone `void` keyword for parameters in the prototype but it no longer has an effect I believe.

Comment: Snap! That is cray cray. That's [`function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) syntax for a function type. Are you saying that we can abandon the C-style function pointer all together now? Did that change sometime? I thought that was illegal?

Comment: @JonathanMee: That comment makes little sense to me. You link to `std::function`, which is a C++ library type. This example is valid since ANSI C'89. Did you perhaps intend to comment on skypjack's answer?

Comment: @MSalters This is just my ignorance, I thought that we always had to have the `void(*)()` syntax. I'd never seen the `void()` syntax outside a `function` type anyway. I guess it's been valid about as long as I've been alive.

Comment: @JonathanMee the syntax exists for way longer than `std::function`, you can write `int (double, short)` to denote a function which returns an integer and takes a double and a short for example. `std::function` just provides a nicer interface

Comment: @JonathanMee: `void(*)()` is a _function **pointer** type_. `void()` is a _function type_. The two are related, but [not the same](http://ideone.com/Od7kvo).

Comment: The question was about the type `void` and the expression `void()`. This answer is about the type `void()`, which is something completely different.

Comment: @interjay the question starts with "I was given a piece of code that uses void() as an argument" so I think this is still related

Comment: Also, what `void()` does in that context is _decaying_, not expanding (it's not a macro).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `void()` as a callable type, as an example `std::function<void()> f;` is a valid statement.

Moreover, as from [8.3.5/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#4):

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type void is equivalent to an empty parameter list.

That means that this is valid:

```
template<typename T>
struct F;

template<typename R, typename... A>
struct F<R(A...)> { };

int main () {
   F<void(void)> s;
}
```

Here you are not instantiating anything of type `void`, but you are using it (let me say) as a parameter list of a callable type.

Not sure if this replies to your question, I've not clear what the question actually is.

Comment: Unless I misread this, you are using `void` as a *type* not *constructing* anything of `void` correct?

Answer (score 1):

> There is no place for void() in C++ is there?

As an expression, `void()` is valid in C++.

From the standard, `$5.2.3/2 Explicit type conversion (functional notation) [expr.type.conv]`:

> The expression `T()`, where `T` is a simple-type-specifier or
>   typename-specifier for a non-array complete object type or the
>   (possibly cv-qualified) `void` type, creates a prvalue of the specified
>   type, whose value is that produced by value-initializing (8.5) an
>   object of type `T`; no initialization is done for the `void()` case.

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast#Explanation):

> new_type ( )
>
> If `new_type` is an object type, the object is value-initialized;
>   otherwise, no initialization is done. If `new_type` is (possibly
>   cv-qualified) `void`, the expression is a `void` prvalue.

Comment: I'm reading from here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast and I see what you're talking about, but I don't see where that works. I mean I tried `void()` in all the contexts I could think of.

Comment: @JonathanMee What context did you try? BTW: T.C. 's answer provids a list for it.