# void{} vs void() as a void initializer

Tags: c++, initialization, void, initializer, list-initialization

The `void()` construction can be used to "create a value of the type `void`" (strange but true). But the C++11+ initialization syntax with curly braces doesn't work in such case:

```
int f_int_parenthesis()
{
    return int();  // OK
}

int f_int_braces()
{
    return int{};  // OK
}

void f_void_parenthesis()
{
    return void(); // OK
}

void f_void_braces()
{
    return void{}; // error
}
```

[The code compilability is checked with *g++ 7.2.0* and *clang++ 3.8.0*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9bcfcdee31be8ac) (compilation flags are `-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -O0`).

Why is it so? Is it a standard-compliant behavior?

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701321/construction-of-a-void-type) the ambiguity of the `void` type ..

Comment: @txtechhelp What do you mean?

Comment: The answers explain a little more with links to the standard, essentially `void()` allows a type `void{}` does not, thus the error.

Comment: [`void{}` is neither a valid type nor a valid expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354065/is-void-legal-or-not).

Comment: `void{}` should be legal soon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53267943/27678

Comment: @AndyG Excellent! :-) Thank you.